# PHP Include will not work

Tags: php, include

I am trying to make a basic HTML page and include a menu from another HTML file. I plan to use this separate HTML file for the menu, so I can just update this file instead of 100+ pages etc. every time I add a new item to the menu.

The problem is I cannot get it to work. Here is my HTML page code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
Text. Here is the menu:
<?php include "menu.html"; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my menu HTML file code:

```
<html>
<ul>
<li><a href="http://google.com">menu item 1</a></li>
<li><a href="http://google.com">menu item 2</a></li>
<li><a href="http://google.com">menu item 3</a></li>
<li><a href="http://google.com">menu item 4</a></li>
</ul>
</html>
```

I can't see what I am doing wrong. When I load the HTMl page it just doesn't show the menu at all. I'm sure its something basic. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you changed the file extension from ".html" to ".php"?

Comment: Thanks that worked! I thought it was something simple I had overlooked! Thanks :)

Comment: You might also want to remove the html tags from the menu file.